# Ruby on Rails: Can't mass-assign protected attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mass-assignment

Searched through all other same questions, nothing worked.
I have User, which can create Track, but can also learn other Tracks.
Learning other Tracks is saved in track_users.

**model User.rb:**

```
# has track as author!
has_many :tracks     
# has track as student!
has_many :tracks_users
has_many :courses, through: :tracks_users, source: :track
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tracks_users
```

**model Track.rb**

```
# has coach!
belongs_to :user
# has students!
has_many :tracks_users
has_many :students, through: :tracks_users, source: :user
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tracks_users
```

**and model TracksUser.rb**:

```
  attr_accessible :track_id, :user_id, :as => [:default, :admin]
  belongs_to :track
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :track
```

and in my tracks/_follow.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.courses.build(track_id: @track)) do |f| %>
    <div><%= f.hidden_field :track_id %></div>
    <%= f.submit "Take track", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

And this throws "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: track_id".
I even set config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false - doesn't work.

Comment: Did you restart the server after setting config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false ?

Comment: The form is for a `Course`, not `user`

Comment: @Albert: of course I restarted.

Comment: @AbM: Courses  is a synonym for relationship tracks_users.

Comment: same result is if I change form from User to Track being leading entity:
    <%= form_for(@track.students.build(user_id: 1)) do |f| %>
        <div><%= f.hidden_field :user_id %></div>
        <%= f.submit "Take track", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is separate configuration option, explicitly for development stage - 
in config/environments/development.rb:

```
# Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
```

Error is gone by outcommenting that.

I have not seen this configuration mentioned anywhere in StackOverflow.
Found it on http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/mass-assignment-rails-and-you/, so thanks tutsplus.